# PHP preg_match error

Tags: php, preg-match

I have been ripping my hair out trying to find out where this error is coming from. Any help resolving this error would be greatly appreciated.

ERROR:

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 9 in /home/internet/public_html/z-insert/functions/dns.php on line 526
```

CODE: -line 526 is the 4th preg_match

```
if (preg_match('/127\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/',$mx_ip[$i]) || 
preg_match('/10\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/',$mx_ip[$i]) ||
preg_match('/192\.168\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/',$mx_ip[$i]) ||
preg_match('/172\.[16-31]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/',$mx_ip[$i])){
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[]` encloses a *character class*, which has no order.  You can create ranges within the character class for convenience, but it must be of the correct syntax.  You can't have the range `6-3`.  You need to do something like this:

```
(?:1[6-9]|2[0-9]|30|31)
```

I'm also not sure whether the `+` there is intentional, but I would guess not.

Answer (score 2):

The character class `[16-31]` is not valid.

It tell: match any charter that is:

1. either a `1` or any
2. any in the range starting from `6` till `3` !!! Which is invalid range.
3. either a `1`

Looks like you want to match any number in the range `16` till `31` for that you can do:

```
1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]
```

where you split the entire range of `16-31` into sub-ranges, write a regex for each sub-range and club all the sub-ranges using the `|` (or operator).

Answer (score 2):

First, as I commented, 16-31 is not a valid range. I suggest you to read [`this article`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html) about numeric ranges in regexps.

As a solution I propose:

* Capture second octet and check it with php:

```
$flag = false;
if (preg_match('/172\.(?P<second_octet>\d+)\.\d+\.\d+/',$mx_ip[$i], $match)) {
    if ($match['second_octet']>=16 && $match['second_cotet'] <= 31) {
        $flag = true;
    }
}
if (preg_match('/127\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/',$mx_ip[$i]) || 
preg_match('/10\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/',$mx_ip[$i]) ||
preg_match('/192\.168\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/',$mx_ip[$i]) || 
$flag
) { ...
```

* Pass numbers from 16 to 31 explicitly:

```
$second_octet_range = range(16,31);
preg_match('/172\.(?:'.implode('|', $second_octet_range).')\.\d+\.\d+/',$mx_ip[$i]);
```

* Go with less readable variant of your regular expression (IMHO, less preferable solution because of lack of readability - you really need some time to understand that second octet's range is 16-31 while in first 2 solutions it's obvious):

```
preg_match('/172\.(?:1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])\.\d+\.\d+/',$mx_ip[$i]);
```